# How do I marshal a mixed-content node? I'm getting a Marshal.Exception

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling, mixed-content

This is a Java JAXB question. I am reading in a mixed-content element from XML and trying to output it in another XML file, but when I try to marshal from the Java classes to my XML output, I get the following error:

> [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class java.util.ArrayList nor
>   any of its super class is known to this context.
>   javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its
>   super class is known to this context.]

The XML element that causes the problem looks like this in the schema:

```
  <xs:element name="manual_description">
    <xs:complexType **mixed="true"**>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element ref="para"/>
          <xs:group ref="docbook_elements"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
...
  <xs:group name="docbook_elements">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element ref="note"/>
      <xs:element ref="literal"/>
      <xs:element ref="link"/>
      <xs:element ref="itemizedlist"/>
      <xs:element ref="informaltable"/>
      <xs:element ref="emphasis"/>
      <xs:element ref="subscript"/>
      <xs:element ref="superscript"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
```

> Note: mixed="true"

I load the schema into Eclipse and use **right-click > Generate > JAXB Classes** to get my Java classes. I don't modify this output. This class ends up looking like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "manual_description")
public class ManualDescription{

@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name = "para", type = Para.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "superscript", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "literal", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "emphasis", type = Emphasis.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "note", type = Note.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "link", type = Link.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "informaltable", type = Informaltable.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "itemizedlist", type = Itemizedlist.class, required = false),
    @XmlElementRef(name = "subscript", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
})
@XmlMixed
protected List<Object> content;

/* comment deleted */

public List<Object> getContent() {
    if (content == null) {
        content = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.content;
}

}
```

My debugger shows that the code correctly populates the entire tree, but when that tree gets fed to the marshaller, the marshaller chokes.

Here's the code that calls the marshaller (inside a try block):

```
        File outputfile = new File(pathandfile);
        JAXBContext jaxbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Descriptions.class);
        Marshaller jaxbm = jaxbc.createMarshaller();

        jaxbm.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        jaxbm.marshal(des, outputfile);
        jaxbm.marshal(des, System.out);
```

These variables are supplied by the calling method:

- **pathandfile**: the pathname and filename of the output file.
- **des**: the fully assembled Java tree

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` class does not have any `JAXB` annotations on it. Due to this JAXB is unable to parse any such java objects and raises this error. This [**article**](http://howtodoinjava.com/jaxb/solved-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-class-java-util-arraylist-nor-any-of-its-super-class-is-known-to-this-context/) explains in details.

In short, you can create wrapper class which holds your list

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "descriptions")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Descriptions 
{
 @XmlElement(name = "description")
 private List<Description> descriptions = null;

 public List<Description> getDescriptions() {
     return descriptions;
 }

 public void setDescriptions(List<Description> descriptions) {
    this.descriptions = descriptions;
 }
}
```

You can setup the description, e.g.

```
Descriptions descriptions = new Descriptions();

Description description = new Description();
// set properties here

descriptions.setDescriptions(new ArrayList<Description>());
```

Lastly;

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Descriptions.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(descriptions, System.out);
```

This is just an example, you may have to change according to your use case.

Comment: The referenced article identifies the problem and provides a good solution, but link-only answers are brittle, because links always seem to go stale (I've had to update my own link-only answers for the same reason). Your answer will be greatly improved if you state the solution, include a simple code sample, and maybe example output (as in the article). That way, it will stay valid forever.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have questions.

My JAXB tree for my output file contains other (non-mixed-type) elements that are lists, and they parse just fine, so the comment about ArrayList  seems off.

The example in the link you provided looks just like those other classes that work, that is, non-mixed-type. That doesn't help.

I do not understand where this "wrapper" class fits in. I do not want it to create a new element in my output XML, so what do I do with it? Create an object that represents the content, then add it to both the wrapper and its parent?